# Proof of trigonometric identity for sine

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, proof-writing

How do I prove that $$\sum_{n=1}^{N} \sin(n\theta)=\frac{1}{2}\cot\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)-\frac{\cos((N+0.5)\theta)}{2\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}? $$

Comment: Hint: write $\sin(n \theta)$ in terms of complex exponentials: you will get geometric series.

Comment: Try using $$\sin(n\theta)=\frac{e^{-in\theta}-e^{in\theta}}{2i}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\sum_{n=1}^N \sin(n\theta) = \left(\text{the imaginary part of } \sum_{n=1}^N e^{in\theta} \right) = \left( \text{the imaginary part of } \sum_{n=1}^N \Big(e^{i\theta} \Big)^n \right).
$$
This is a geometric series with common ratio $e^{i\theta}$ and you have a standard formula for summing those.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Write
$$2\sin k\theta\sin\dfrac{\theta}{2}=\cos(k-\dfrac{1}{2})\theta-\cos(k+\dfrac{1}{2})\theta$$
$$2\sin\dfrac{\theta}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n\sin k\theta=\sum_{k=1}^n\Big(\cos(k-\dfrac{1}{2})\theta-\cos(k+\dfrac{1}{2})\theta\Big)=\cos(\dfrac{1}{2})\theta-\cos(n+\dfrac{1}{2})\theta$$